# How do I prevent blank characters in my textarea in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, textarea

I have a text area where I do not allow users to double space or enter. The problem I saw is that some users use the https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2800 to create blank space. How can I prevent that in Javascript (React)

Answer (score 0):

With regex you can validate the value i think.

Something like this :

```
/[\s\u2800]{2,}/gmu
```

#### Other ressource

[link to codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-kare-rhr9k?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

[Link to regex101 with my test](https://regex101.com/r/nQQVfU/1)

#### Definition

```
\s => any whitespace character
\u2800 => Matches the unicode character with the given hex value
{2,} => 2 or more
/g => don't return after first match
/m => multi line
/u => match with full unicode (maybe useless)
```